# use ngif to hide a row in mat-table

Tags: angular, mat-table

I am trying to hide a row after I click on a button in the mat-table. I don't know where to put `*ngIf`. I tried on `ng-container` but it does not work. Below is my HTML file.

```
<mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="application">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let application">{{application.id}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let application">{{application.name}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="ApplicationDate">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Application Date</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let application">{{application.applyDate}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="TrackingNumber">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Tracking Number</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let application">{{application.trackNumber}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Operation">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Operation</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let application">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onClickGrant()">Grant</button>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onClickDeny()">Deny</button>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,15,20]" [pageSize]="5" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Please add the TS code that would impact a variable used in the `*ngIf`.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to do this is just to update your `[dataSource]` after the click event and not to do any Material gymnastics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The other way is to add class to `mat-row` and use CSS to hide it.

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="..." [class.hidden]="YOUR_IF_HERE"></mat-row>
```

You can look also on similar example from Angualr Material site:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/voqbanbobpa?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

Comment: correct. `ngStyle` / `ngClass` would probably be more appropriate here though

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `dataSource` object from the component code, `application` in your case, and remove the row you want to hide.

It depends on your component code, but you will most likely do:

```
this.application = this.application.splice(i, 1);
```